# What is the best practice for writing methods that are opposite of each other when returning a boolean?

Tags: java, conventions

I am learning about conditionals and want to know if this is a bad convention for similar situations. Should I define isOdd() without using isEven()?

```
    static boolean isEven(int i) {
        return i % 2 == 0;
    }
    
    static boolean isOdd(int i) {
        return !isEven(i);  
    }
```

Comment: There isn't a convention because this is not a common practice.

Comment: In a real code, you would not write a method for such a tiny piece of code. And for larger piece of codes, you would of course NOT write the method twice. IMO, this is a not a "real world" problem.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to best practice instead. Is that any better?

Comment: I think that make more sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's absolutely fine, and code reuse is positively encouraged - if you actually need both methods, of course. Is it really too hard for the caller to use `!isEven(...)`? Sometimes it *can* be worth it for the sake of caller readability, but I'd encourage careful consideration first.

However, what I *would* discourage is the approach of `isEven` using an `if` statement where the body just returns true or false. That can always be replaced by just returning the condition:

```java
static boolean isEven(int i) {
    return i % 2 == 0;
}
```

Comment: I see. Thanks. And wow! I didn't see that, will fix my code now.

Answer (score 1):

Such a method is overkill. Just checking if isEven returns false will tell you that it is odd.

Comment: Oh that's true. Is that common practice even for big projects? Like omitting the latter.

Comment: I think Jon answers this question above, "... if you actually need both methods, of course. Is it really too hard for the caller to use !isEven(...)? Sometimes it can be worth it for the sake of caller readability, but I'd encourage careful consideration first."

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll definitely consider this in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any specific convention for that.

I would choose the reuse strategy, so you just have to maintain only 1 implementation in case of correction or evolution. And you (or your successor) won't forget to update half the code...

Answer (score 0):

A more common occurrence where you might face this question is when instances of a class have a natural order, and can be compared with each other.

In Java, you would implement the `compareTo(T)` method of [`Comparable`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) As the notes say, it is recommended that `compareTo()` be consistent with `equals()`. One way to ensure that and maximize your code reuse is to define `equals()` in terms of `compareTo()`:

```java
final class MyComparable implements Comparable<MyComparable> {

    /* Some fields that are used for sorting. */
    ... 

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyComparable that) {
       /* Compare the fields of this and that and return a signed result */
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        /* Define hash in terms of members used for sorting too. */
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        /* Re-use the definition of natural ordering to define equality. */
        return (obj instanceof MyComparable) && (compareTo((MyComparable) obj) == 0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed good practice in many situations. Sometimes, the Java API source code can be a good example of good practice.

In Java 8, the class `Optional` has a method `isPresent()`, and users who wanted to know if an object was not present would have to use `!isPresent()`.

In Java 11, they've added `Optional.isEmpty()`, and the source code for that is just `return !isPresent();`. It was added because it was found to be desirable by many users in practice.

Comment: Wow thank you! I will check those out now